# $0 \subset (x_1 - a_1) \subset (x_1 - a_1, x_2-a_2) \subset ... \subset (x_1-a_1,..., x_n - a_n)$ is a (strictly) ascending chain of prime ideals

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals, maximal-and-prime-ideals, euclidean-algorithm

I saw the following exercise in Sharp's text book:

> Let $K$ be a field,  and let $R = K[x_1,...,x_n]$ be the ring of polynomials over $K$ in indeterminates $x_1,...,x_n$; let $a_1,...,a_n \in K$. Show that, in $R$, 
>   $$0 \subset (x_1 - a_1) \subset (x_1 - a_1, x_2-a_2) \subset ... \subset (x_1-a_1,..., x_n - a_n)$$ is a (strictly) ascending chain of prime ideals.

My attempt: I will show that $ J_1 = (x_1 - a_1),...,J_n=(x_1-a_1,..., x_n - a_n)$ are a maximal ideals of $R$. I already know that $J_n$ is a maximal ideal of $R$, the problem is $J_i,\ \text{for}\ i \in \{1,...,n-1\}$.

Let $I$ be a ideal of $R$ such that $J_1 \subset I \subseteq R$, i.é, exist $f \in I$ such that $f \notin J_1$. We have that
$$f =  q(x_1-a_1) + r   \hspace{2cm}(1)$$
for some $q, r \in R$ with $\text{degree}(r) <  \text{degree}(x_1-a_1) = 1$ or $r = 0$. Since $f \notin J$ we have $\text{degree}(r) = 0 \hspace{3cm} (2)$
So...??

My questions:

for (1): Since $K$ is a field we have that $R$ is a Euclidean Domain and then we can apply the algorithm in (1), right??

for (2): What can we say about $r$, since $\text{degree}(r) = 0$? I got a feeling that is not true that $r \in K$.

Maybe this approach is not correct, but I can not think of any other approach by using the other characterization of prime ideals : $P$ is a prime ideal of $R$ if, and only if, $R/P$ is a integral domain.

Comment: "I will show that $ J_1 = (x_1 - a_1),...,J_n=(x_1-a_1,..., x_n - a_n)$ are a maximal ideals of $R$." We have $J_i\subsetneq J_n$ for $i<n$. By definition they can't be maximal.

Comment: That’s correct, so I don’t have any clue how to solve this exercise

Comment: $K[x_1]$ is an Euclidean domain, but $K[x_1,x_2]$ isn't: Without even thinking about any $r$, it's clear that the Euclidean algorithm can't be used on $\gcd(x_1,x_2)=1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quotienting out by any of these ideals, say $(x_1-a_1,...,x_k-a_k)$, gives the ring $K[x_{k+1},...,x_n]$, which is an integral domain. I'll leave the details to you.

Comment: Nit-pick: You get something which is _isomorphic_ to $K[x_{k+1},\ldots,x_n]$.

Comment: I don't think this is a necessary distinction to make. As you take the quotient you carry along the symbols $x_{k+1}, ..., x_n$ and there is no reason to think of this ring as anything but $K[x_{k+1},...,x_n]$.

Comment: That's how you think about it, and that's how I think about it. I do not know, however, whether the OP is at the level where it is as intuitively obvious as it is to you and me.

Comment: Just wondering: to which question addresses this answer?

Comment: It was addressed at the idea in the last paragraph because the proceeding portion was based on the mistaken notion that these ideals are maximal (as Arthur explained in the question's comments)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried pick $\psi: R \to K[x_{k+1},...,x_n]$ given by $\psi(f) = f(a_1,..., a_k, x_{k+1},...,x_n)$. How can I show that $\text{Ker}(\psi)= \{ f \in R : f(a_1,..., a_k, x_{k+1},...,x_n) = 0\} = (x_1-a_1,..., x_k-a_k)$?

Comment: The hard part is showing that $K[x_1,...,x_n]$ is a UFD. If you haven't seen this, consult an algebra book for the proof that if $R$ is a UFD then $R[X]$ is. By induction, this implies that $K[x_1, ..., x_n]$ is a UFD (because $K[x_1,...,x_n] = (((K[x_1])[x_2])...)[x_n]$).

Comment: Okay, but how $K[x_1,...,x_n]$ being UFD helps?

Comment: @P.G Each of the $x_i - a_i$ is irreducible. Can you see how this might help?

Comment: @JonHillery Sorry, I know that irreducibles over UFD are primes, but still don't see how this help

Comment: @P.G Sorry, I think I misremembered your question or something. It's actually not this complicated. Let $f$ be in the kernel of $\psi$, i.e. $f(a_1,...,a_k,x_{k+1},...x_n)=0$. Now, take $f$ mod $(x_1-a_1,...,x_k-a_k)$, which in particular sends $x_1$ to $a_1$, $x_2$ to $a_2$, etc. and therefore $f$ is equivalent to $f(a_1,...,a_k,x_{k+1},...x_n)$ mod $(x_1-a_1, ..., x_k-a_k)$. This is zero, so $f$ is in $(x_1-a_1, ..., x_k-a_k)$. This is basically the intuition behind why I knew that $K[x_1,...x_n]/(x_1-a_1,...x_k-a_k) = K[x_{k+1},...,x_n]$ - you're basically just replacing the first variables

Comment: with scalars and since $K$ is an integral domain there's no weird torsion or anything.

Comment: This "$f$ mod $(x_1-a_1,...,x_k-a_k)$'' is not familiar for me, can you please tell me some book where I can look it?

Comment: @P.G I'm just saying what $f$ gets sent to in $K[x_1,...,x_n]/(x_1 - a_1, ..., x_k-a_k)$ ("$K[x_1,...,x_n]$ modulo $(x_1 - a_1, ..., x_k-a_k)$")